# Al tratar de publicar mi aplicación, solo se ejecuta correctamente desde la carpeta Release pero el ejecutable Publish no funciona

Tags: c#, .net-core, deployment, visual-studio-2019

estoy tratando de crear un ejecutable de mi proyecto, ya que se trata de un proyecto de fin de grado y necesito enviarselo al profesor, el problema que tengo es que no hay forma de conseguir ejecutarlo, cuando trato de publicar el archivo con esta configuración.

[image: Opciones de publicación]

No importa que cambios haga en la configuración, siempre genera una publicación supuestamente exitosa

[image: Salida del programa]

Pero que al tratar de ejecutarla, tras mostrar un rato el icono de carga, no se muestra la ventana

[image: Archivos generados]

Sin embargo si ejecuto el archivo que se encuentra en Release no en publish, si que se ejecuta la aplicación perfectamente, pero claro ese archivo es dependiente de la plataforma en el mismo momento que se mueve a otro sitio falla.
[image: Ejecución en release netcoreapp3.1]

Hasta ahora he probado usando la última opción "Quitar los ensablados no usados" y activar que se muestren los errores de ReadyToRun, haciendolo de esta forma indica que le falta el nuget inmutable de collections, lo instalo, vuelvo a probar entonces me dice que no puede cargar 2 componentes, invoke y websocket, y cuando busco la solución a esto, la única que encuentro es una de la versión inglesa de esta pagina (stackoverflow) que el usuario lo soluciono quitando la opción de "Quitar los emsamblados no usados" con lo que me quedo como al principio.

El código y cualquier cosa que necesiten se encuentra en github por si quisieran inspeccionarlo más a fondo https://github.com/davidgmd/Proyecto-de-fin-de-grado Ahora mismo estoy usando la rama calendario, aparte de eso me pongo a su entera disposición para cualquier información que pueda faltar, ya que no se me ocurre que más hacer la verdad.

**Editado:** Al usar el visor de eventos, aparecian 2 mensajes de error, uno que hacia referencia a kernelbase, no da detalles de porque y el otro que parece el más importante, que indico aquí

> Application: ElEscribaDelDJ.exe CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.41105 .NET
> Core Version: 3.1.8 Description: The process was terminated due to an
> unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the
> constructor on type 'ElEscribaDelDJ.MainWindow' that matches the
> specified binding constraints threw an exception. --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'ElEscribaDelDJ.Classes.GitHub' threw an exception. --->
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path
> 'C:\Users\David2\AppData\Local\Temp\Classes\Keys\encriptkeys.txt'. at
> System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle) at
> System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare
> share, FileOptions options) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,
> FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
> FileOptions options) at
> System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding
> encoding, Int32 bufferSize) at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String
> path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) at
> System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding) at
> System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path) at
> ElEscribaDelDJ.Classes.GitHub..ctor() at
> ElEscribaDelDJ.Classes.GitHub..cctor() --- End of inner exception
> stack trace --- at ElEscribaDelDJ.MainWindow..ctor() --- End of inner
> exception stack trace --- at
> System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e,
> IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri) at
> System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
> IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
> skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
> settings, Uri baseUri) at
> System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
> Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
> accessLevel, Uri baseUri) at
> System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
> parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream) at
> System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream,
> ParserContext pc) at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri
> resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties) at
> System.Windows.Application.DoStartup() at
> System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused) at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() at
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
> state) at
> MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object
> obj) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) --- End of
> stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
> MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
> msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
> IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o) at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
> priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
> numArgs) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
> msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg) at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
> frame) at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() at
> System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore) at
> System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window) at
> System.Windows.Application.Run() at ElEscribaDelDJ.App.Main()

Veo que supuestamente da error porque no localiza un archivo, lo que no se es porque ese archivo no es empaquetado junto al resto de archivos, o que es lo que hace que no funcione en otra carpeta que no sea o la de debug o la de release

Comment: Mira bien en esa carpeta, hay otra llamada "publish", revisa dentro de esta. O mejor dicho, realiza una publicación en otra carpeta como C:\Dev\Publish

Comment: Es verdad, como dijo @fredyfx, puedes seleccionar otra carpeta para el perfil, en el campo Ubicación de destino, he intentar correrlo desde allí.

Comment: ya he probado eso, pero no funciona, por ejemplo con una carpeta en el el escritorio, C:\Users\David2\Desktop\proyecto, ocurre lo mismo me genera 2 archivos, el .exe y un archivo .pdb y al ejecutar el archivo .exe muestra el icono de carga 3 veces, y listo no hace nada y no muestra ni si quiera mensaje de error.

Comment: Otra cos que puede estar pasando, no se si es el caso, pero yo recuerdo que malwarebytes ponía en cuarentena mis .exes, no se si sea tu caso que algún antivirus este bloqueando algo.

Comment: Puedes loggear los errores a un archivo txt, tu proyecto es una aplicación de consola?

Otra forma de ver porque fallo es usando el EventViewer o visor de eventos de windows

[Mira este Ejemplo](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/02/14/net-core-console-logging/)

Comment: Acabo de probar lo del antivirus añadiendolo como excepción al windows defender que es el único que tengo ahora mismo y no funciono.

Comment: usando el visor de eventos he encontrado lo que parece ser la posible raiz del problema, aunque no entiendo porque ocurre esto, voy a editar mi publicación y añado esa información

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error en el evenvt viewer de windows es:

> Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'ElEscribaDelDJ.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
> ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ElEscribaDelDJ.Classes.GitHub' threw an exception.
> ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Tutoriales\ProjectoFin\Proyecto-de-fin-de-grado-master\WpfApp2\bin\Classes\Keys\encriptkeys.txt'.

Ya revise tu código y parece que estas buscando un archivo en una ruta especifica.

En tu código estas buscando ese archivo en esa ruta exacta: Classes\Keys\encriptkeys.txt

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese archivo tiene que existir en tu publish folder.
Te recomiendo que agregues ese archivo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizaciones:

Si Copiar siempre no funciona, solo asegúrate de tener Classes\Keys\encriptkeys.txt en tu publish folder.

```
string path = RecursosAplicacion.DireccionBase + "\\Classes\\Keys\\encriptkeys.txt";
```

En la linea de código anterior `RecursosAplicacion.DireccionBase` parece que ese directorio no esta funcionando, si esos valores van a estar fijos en el código mejor agrégalos como variables en lugar de leerlos de un archivo, si los vas a cambiar es mejor que tengas el archivo junto con el exe, en la misma raíz o en otra carpetea como tu guste, pero tendrías que cambiar `RecursosAplicacion.DireccionBase` por algo como `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Actualizacion 2:

Si mira yo cambiaria todos los archivos que necesitas en publish folder para que se copien automáticamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y después la parte para obtener la ruta quedaría algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto aplica para todos los archivos que este leyendo desde tu aplicación.

Comment: De acuerdo, explico entonces cual era mi intención porque visto los errores que esta dando es imposible hacerlo tal como tenia en mente, mi idea era que fueran fijos relativos a donde este el programa, es decir al instalar el programa este tuviera unas carpetas concretas y diferentes archivos, pero al ejecutarlo externamente en vez de buscarlos en donde esta el archivo, los busca en Appdata/local/temp, lo cual obviamente no es lo ideal, ¿Debería usar system.reflection.assembly para cada uno de esos archivos? ¿y como me aseguro que al instalar la aplicación esten esos archivos y carpetas?

Comment: system.reflection.assembly <-- esto seria para obtener la carpeta de donde se esta ejecutando la aplicación, pero puedes crear el archivo encriptkeys.txt si no existe y lo puedes crear donde tu quieras, en temp o en c, o en la misma ruta del proyecto.

Si lo vas dejar en el mismo folder que el ejecutable entonces si usa reflexión y has que se copie automático el archivo